# How to access an NFS share from any computer in any network

Tags: nfs, cloud

Is it possible to specify a client host in the exports file in such a way that I can mount the NFS share from any computer in any network, or would I have to use something like openmediavault or nextcloud for this?
Currently the line in the exports file is
`/media/xxx/nfs2      192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync)`
and I understand that clients with that IP adress ending on 0 to 255 can mount the share.

How would I mount the nfs share, would I need to put in the public IP address like this:

`sudo mount xx.64.xxx.175:/media/xxx/nfs2 /home/xxxx/nfs2`

Comment: The two are not the same concept. If you want outside access set up an SSH server https://www.openssh.com/.  NFS can be used to create a share. https://bluexp.netapp.com/blog/azure-anf-blg-linux-nfs-server-how-to-set-up-server-and-client

Comment: Thanks, I do have SSH installed on the Raspberry Pi and I am able to log into it from any network using the public ip adress. So I can use ssh somehow to mount the nfs share ?

Comment: with ssh you can do `ssh {user}@xx.64.xxx.175 "ls -l /media/xxx/nfs2" and use `rcp` to copy files (`rcp  {user}@xx.64.xxx.175:/media/xxx/nfs2/file.txt .`

Answer (score 0):

As pointes out by Rinzwind, file transfer is possible via the rcp command.
I assume that a remote integration of the share folder into the GUI file system and for direct use of Ubuntu apps is not possible.